# Trying to center a div tag within a section tag

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to center my div tag within a section tag. I can get it centered from left to right but not top and bottom in the center of the section tag. If I give a margin-top:xxpx then it moves the section tag down and exposes it (not good!)

Here is my css

```
body 
{
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0;
}

header > * {
margin: 0;
float: left;
}

header
{
background-color: white ;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
}

/*header > input {
margin: 10px 20px 0px 10px;
}*/

#toptext
{
margin: 10px 5px 0px 10px;
width: 245px;
}

article > * {
margin: 0;
}

article
{
background-color: red;
}

#search {
background-color: #a6dbed;
height: 500px;
}

#middlesearch {
background-color: grey;
width: 700px;
margin: 0 auto;   
}

#mostdesired 
{
background-color: #c7d1d6;
height: 200px;
}

section h2 {
margin:0;
}

.site-title {
color: #c8c8c8;
font-family: Rockwell, Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size: 1.3em;
margin: 0px 20px 0px 50px;
margin-top: 7px;
}

.site-title a, .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:active {
background: none;
color: #c8c8c8;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is my html

```
<body>
    <header>
        <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Site", "Index", "Home")</p>
        <input id="toptext" type="text" />
    </header>
    <article>
        <section id="search">
            <div id="middlesearch">
                <h2>Search Here</h2>@RenderBody()
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="mostdesired" ><h2>This is the most section</h2></section>
    </article>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertically aligning with CSS is notoriously tricky.

Change the CSS to

```
#search {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #a6dbed;
    height: 500px;
}

#middlesearch {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 700px;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px; /* half the width */
}
```

and add one line of JQuery to up the div to be correctly centered

```
$('#middlesearch').css("margin-top",-$('#middlesearch').height()/2)
```

this line can be avoided if you decide to explicitly specify the height of the div at which point you can simply define the top margin in the CSS.

This avoids having to use tables.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS declaration for header isn't closed on line 20

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Unfortunately, CSS doesn't make it to easy, but it is possible. Since the div height is dynamic, I would recommend the CSS table method. Yes, a total hack, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little work for block level elements, refer to these examples

http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: what about replacing the section tag with a div tag? Would it be easy then?

Answer (score -1):

```
#middlesearch {
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:500px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: it moves the div tag with color grey to the left side of the screen and doesn't center it. It tried with my code. If it works for you can you show me the code?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't recreated your code. I was only providing a method for vertically aligning things in block elements to the middle. If it helps, here it is with the inner content of #search vertically aligning to the middle: http://jsfiddle.net/AeLfw/